# How to use ajax to navigate to multiple files

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function disableHandler() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to Disable Penalty Marks?" + "\n" + "(You cannot change your option once you have confirmed)" + "\n")) {
        $.when($.ajax({
            url: "sessioncomplete.php",
            async: false,
            type: "POST"
        })).then(window.location = "complete.php");
        return true;
    }
}
```

In code above I use ajax in order to navigate to a page and then after the ajax has completed navigating to that page, it then re-locate to the `complete.php` session.

But I have never done this before but I realise I need a second page to be navigated through ajax before re-locating to the `complete.php` page. So I want the ajax to navigate to 2 pages `penaltyinsert.php first then sessioncomplete.php` and then re-locate to `sessioncomplete.php`.

My question is where and what is correct way of do I put the second ajax call?

Comment: Do they need to run in sequence, or can the calls both occur at the same time?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Better if it is done by sequence, penaltyinsert.php first, then sessioncomplete.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ajax` `success` function instead of `$.when` and `then`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "penaltyinsert.php",
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(result){
            $.ajax({
                 url: "sessioncomplete.php",
                 async: false,
                 type: "POST",
                 success:function(response){
                      window.location = "complete.php"
                  };
               })
        };
    })
```